# FireMonkey: Target Platform

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Hello I started working with FireMonkey. And I have a question as to enable Target Platform Win32 in FireMonkey Mobile? Why do I not have it?

[image]

Comment: @KenWhite - Win32 builds in a 'mobile' project are for quick debugging (cf. http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/fmx_mobile_preview_xe5upd2.html). Strictly speaking there's no 'FireMonkey Mobile' - desktop and mobile FMX projects are essentially identical.

Comment: My words above were in reply to a now-deleted comment if anyone's wondering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the Target Platforms node; a popup menu should appear with an Add Platform item. Click on it and choose 32-bit Windows in the resulting dialog.